# Bitcoin promotional campaigns

Tags: project, promotion

Have there been any notable promotional campaigns for the Bitcoin project or some of the major Bitcoin-relatd websites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has been a bitcoin [billboard](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=7961.msg170045#msg170045) on the Lawrence Expressway in Silicon Valley, California, paid for by memmorydealers.com.
[image]

Also the same company paid for a [radio advertisement](http://bitcoinmedia.com/how-to-get-bitcoins-with-cash-national-radio) across a number of US radio stations I believe.

Comment: Added an image of the billboard. Perhaps it is a bit too large?

Answer (score 4):

Mt.Gox [donated over 4000$](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/j6l7f/mtgox_donates_409600_to_the_humble_indie_bundle/) to [Humble Indie Bundle 3](http://www.humblebundle.com/). Whereas it wasn't a direct campaign for Bitcoins, it got noticed in a few places helping to promote the currency's image.